# MySQL Duplicate on Insert

Tags: mysql, inner-join, insert-update

First table

```
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists mainInfo (
sku varchar(20) primary key not null,
name varchar(20) not null,
price int(30) not null,
type int(2) not null
)";
```

Second Table

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS properties (
size int(9),
bWeight int(9),
fHeight int(9),
fWeight int(9),
fLenght int(9),
sku varchar(20) not null,
CONSTRAINT FK_mainInfoProperties FOREIGN KEY (sku) REFERENCES mainInfo(sku)
)";
```

Inner join table

```
      $sql = "CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS allInfo (
        sku varchar(20) primary key not null,
        name varchar(20) not null,
        price int(30) not null,
        type int(2) not null,
        size int(9),
        bWeight int(9),
        fHeight int(9),
        fWeight int(9),
        fLenght int(9)
         )";

       $sql = "INSERT INTO allInfo (sku, name, price, type, size, bWeight, 
       fHeight, fWeight, fLenght)
        SELECT mainInfo.sku, name, price, type, size, bWeight, fHeight, 
       fWeight, fLenght
        FROM mainInfo INNER JOIN properties
        ON mainInfo.sku = properties.sku";
```

First time i use this code it works, but when i add new rows to first and second table, inner join table doesn't update it, giving me duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' how can i update this table adding new rows but leaving the ones that are already there untouched?

Comment: You have `sku` as the primary key, which means that only one row with a specific sku can exists (they must be unique). The `properties` table probably contains multiple rows with the same sku. Do you really want `allInfo` to have `sku` as primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Suk Field in **allInfo as foreign key**   and add new primary key like allInfoId  to identify record uniquely

Comment: did that, but now when i add new information the previous one duplicates in database.   Like :  if i add entry_1, and latter entry_2 it will display it as entry_1 entry_1 entry_2

Comment: was thinking, maybe i could drop table every time before adding new information ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need third table. You easily get the unique record using simple join .

```
Select m.sku ,a.bWeight, a.fHeight, a.fWeight , a.fLenght from mainfon join properties a on m.sku=a.suk where a.suk=your_id
```

I suggested two use only two table,don't use second one